# Can't put @entity annotation in auditable class

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, lombok

This is my class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="usercontext")
public class UserContext extends AbstractAuditable<UserDO, Long> {

  @Column(name="name") private String name;
  @Column(name="value") private String value;
  ...
}
```

I am using lombok (hence @Data annotation). Eclipse editor complains that "The entity has no primary key attribute defined" although the code compiles properly and runs. This same error is shown in JPA problems in markers list in eclipse. AbstractAuditable extends AbstractPersistable which already has a primary key called "id" defined. Is there any way to remove these errors?

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractAuditable` needs to be annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` in order for `id` to be visible to subclasses, and that `id` should be annotated with `@Id`.

Comment: Also, AbstractAuditable must be in the same persistence unit and Eclipse project as UserContext.

Comment: yes it is the same project. "same persistence unit", what does that mean? btw, I am using lombok (edited my question), does that effect anything?

Comment: A persistence unit is defined in your persistence.xml file. Do you have one of those? When you say your code "compiles properly and runs", what do you mean? Are you using JPA to read and write the database? If so, that means you must have a persistence.xml file. Maybe add a code snippet from AbstractAuditable?